# fixed positions filling up div

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage where I would like all the elements fixed in place so that there are no scrollbars for the page as a whole. I have a header, a menu on the left side, and an area where a plot will appear and then directly below the plot should be a list.

There is a gap between the header and the plot area that I can't get rid of. I have the margins and padding already set to 0.

Also, the plot should be taking up 60% of the room below the header and the list 40%, but neither are correct and both elements end well above the bottom of the page in the vertical.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.float {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  padding-top: 60px;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}
.main_title {
  width: 70%;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
}
.clock {
  width: 30%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: green;
}
.header {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu {
  width: 130px;
  flex: 0 0 130px;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
.column_main {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: purple;
  padding-left: 130px;
  float: right;
}
.plot-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: brown;
  height: 60%;
}
#list {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="main_title">title</div>
      <div class="clock">time</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="float">
    <nav class="menu">
      <p>menu</p>
    </nav>
    <div class="column_main">
      <div class="plot-wrapper">
        <p>plot wrapper</p>
      </div>
      <div id="list">
        <p>list</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: "I have a webpage where I would like all the elements fixed in place so that there are no scrollbars for the page as a whole." totally confusing.

Comment: Inside `plot-wrapper` you have `p {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}` set `margin: 0`

Comment: Regarding the height, since your parent container `.float` does not have a height, `height: 60%` for `.plot-wrapper` won't work.

Comment: You are looking for the "flexbox holy grail layout", search google and you will get a multitude of examples...

Comment: Hi. I looked into the holy grail layout and I think I copied some of it, but it was getting the central content stuff (in the holy grail example) divided into two parts of different sizes that got me. I think Marc's solution looks like exactly what I need. That's for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your right, the following is one way of doing it that does not involve using `flex`.

In the header, I use floats to place the two elements side by side.

I then use absolute positioning to create the `.float` panel, adjusting the top offset to set the top edge right below the `header`, and stretching it full width and to the bottom by setting all other offsets to zero.

I then use absolute positioning to place the `.menu` to the left, taking up the left 130px width of the block, and then simarly to create a the  `.column_main` block such that it takes up the remainder of the space.

Within `.column_main`, I keep `.plot-wrapper` and `#list` as regular in-flow elements and set the heights to 60% and 40% respectively.  I add `overflow: auto` so as to prevent any margins (on `p` elements for example) from collapsing and creating unwanted whitespace.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
}
.main_title {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}
.clock {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: green;
}
.float {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
}
.menu {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 130px;
}
.column_main {
  position: absolute;
  left: 130px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: purple;
}
.plot-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: brown;
  height: 60%;
}
#list {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="main_title">title</div>
  <div class="clock">time</div>
</div>
<div class="float">
  <nav class="menu">
    <p>menu</p>
  </nav>
  <div class="column_main">
    <div class="plot-wrapper">
      <p>plot wrapper</p>
    </div>
    <div id="list">
      <p>list</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I meant. It looks like a great solution. Thanks so much!

Comment: You are very welcome, remember to accept the answer to mark the question as answered. Upvote would also be appreciated.  Welcome to SO!

Comment: Site won't register my upvote yet, but it looks like it will when I get some karma points (or whatever they are called on stackoverflow). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a bit but I was confused in your explanation, so I did this, If I am incorrect I apologize but hey I tried. :D

HTML:

```
<div id="page">
    <header class="main-hdr">
        <div>
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div>00:00:00</div>
    </header>
    <main class="main-content">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <section>
            <h2>Plot</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. 
            </p>
        </section>
        <aside>
            <h3>Lists</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
            </ul>
    </main>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300);

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif;
}


body {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /*prevent scrollbars*/
}

header, main, section, aside, nav {
    display: block;
}

#page,
.main-hdr {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.main-hdr {

    display: flex;
}

.main-hdr div {
    float: left;
}

.main-hdr div:first-child {
    background-color: #aa0b6b;
    width: 80%;
}

.main-hdr div:last-child {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #20aa5c;
}

.main-content {
    clear: both;
}

.main-content nav {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

.main-content section {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}

.main-content aside {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
```

RESULT:

[EXAMPLE](https://output.jsbin.com/salixa/1)

Comment: Thank you for trying and I'm sorry if I was confusing. I want the list to come directly below the plot  -- So a vertical menu (that runs from below the header to the bottom of the page) on the left of the window. Then a plot, then directly below that, a list, in ALL the space not taken up by the header or menu (the plot and the list combined would run from directly below the header to the bottom of the page). Both the plot and the list would go horizontally from the menu on the left to the right hand side of the window. I don't know if that clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wkz09uobigUoPbrPiVKK?p=preview)** and a snippet below:

```css
html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 400 16px/1.5'Palatino Linotype';
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
body {
  color: #111;
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.shell {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.core {
  width: calc(100% - 130px);
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  background-color: blue;
  left: 130px;
  top: 60px;
  position: fixed;
}
.title {
  width: 70%;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: central;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 14px;
}
.clock {
  width: 30%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: lime;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
header {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 11;
  position: fixed;
}
.menu {
  width: 130px;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
.plot {
  width: calc(100% - 130px);
  background-color: brown;
  height: calc(60% - 30px);
  top: 60px;
  left: 130px;
  position: fixed;
}
#list {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: calc(100% - 130px);
  height: calc(40% - 30px);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 130px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
}
#list dd {
  text-indent: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="shell">
    <header class="header">

      <h1 class="title">title</h1>
      <h3 class="clock">time</h3>

    </header>

    <nav class="menu">
      <h3>Menu</h3>
    </nav>
    <main class="core">
      <section class="plot">
        <h2>plot wrapper</h2>
      </section>

      <dl id="list">
        <dt>List Section</dt>
        <dd>List Item</dd>
        <dd>List Item</dd>
        <dd>List Item</dd>
        <dd>List Item</dd>
        <dd>List Item</dd>
      </dl>
    </main>


  </section>
</body>

</html>
```